# Apache server on Fedora

Tags: apache, installation, config, fedora

So I followed this guide to a T when setting up apache on my Fedora machine: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_a_Fedora_Linux_Based_Web_Server#Requirements_for_Configuring_a_Web_Server

I was unable to get a static IP so I used the dnsExit route and got that configured fine. I entered

```
/sbin/service httpd status
```

and it said that apache was running. I setup the config file as specified within that article. I reset the apache server to ensure the settings saved... I am not able to access my site externally OR internally. It's clear that there is an issue, however I am fairly new to this... so I honestly do not know where to even begin troubleshooting for this sort of thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I cannot find much documentation for people who can't access the site internally or externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you give is old ? because at this time, on Fedora, we are using "systemctl" to enable and start services.

This is a better way:

```
sudo yum install httpd
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

Check with

```
sudo systemctl status httpd
```

Then, you can configure your settings and use

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Then check if http port is open, at first try to shutdown firewall with

```
sudo systemctl firewalld stop
```

If it's ok, relaunch firewall (systemctl firewalld start) and use "firewall-config" tool to open http port in external and internal zones

Comment: I appreciate your help. It's still not working, so I believe that this is an issue with dnsExit. 

thank you!